# How to create a nested dictionary from a list of values in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

Let's say I have a list that looks like this

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

This list contains a nested list of keys.  From this list, I would like to create a dict like this:

```
{"foo": {"bar": {"baz": {}}}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to get `{"foo": {"bar": {"baz": {}}}`?

Comment: What do you mean by  => ?

Comment: Recursion is the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple recursive function:

```
def nest(l, d=None):
    if d is None: d = {}
    k = l.pop()
    return l and nest(l, {k: d}) or {k: d}
```

To call the function with no side effects to the original list, you can pass in a shallow slice copy:

```
nest(l[:])
```

Comment: @Ben thanks for noticing Ben, I've fixed it to use `None` as the default argument.

Comment: @Shashank what is the return statement doing?  I really don't how to read that.  Can you please explain?

Comment: @dr.jekyllandme Sure. If the list `l` has any elements, it will return the return value of the recursive call to `nest`, but if it's empty, it will just return a dictionary with the final key pointing to the accumulated dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

In order to let program be readable, I modify factorial a bit.
Because learning how to use Recursion, Factorial and Fibonacci is so basic for beginner.

```
a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

def recursion(arr):    
    if len(arr)==0:
        return {}
    else:
        key = arr.pop()
        return {key: recursion(arr)}

print recursion(a)
```